# What does char a[50][50] mean in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm working on a homework that has to do with strings.
Here's the code

```
int main(){
    char a[50][50];
    int n;
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter %d names\n",n);
    fflush(stdin);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        gets(a[i]);
    }
```

I tried to change the char a[50][50] into char a[50] but the entire program didn't run, came along with this error message: "Invalid conversion from 'char' to '*char'
I don't really understand how this works.

Comment: [Beginner's Tutorial](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/) or try any other C book of your choice.

Comment: Two things unrelated to your problem: First of all ***never ever*** use the `gets` function, it's [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) and have been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Second, passing a read-only `FILE` stream to `fflush` (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned as *undefined behavior* in the C specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char a[50][50]` declares `a` as a 50-element array of 50-element arrays of `char`.  That means each `a[i]` is a 50-element array of `char`.  It will be laid out in memory like:

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0][0]
   +---+
   |   | a[0][1]
   +---+
   |   | a[0][2]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[0][49]
   +---+
   |   | a[1][0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1][1]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[1][49]
   +---+
   |   | a[2][0]
   +---+ 
    ...
```

This code is storing up to 50 *strings*, each up to 49 characters long, in `a` (IOW, each `a[i]` can store a 49-character string).  In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  For example, the string `"hello"`, is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  That trailing `0` marks the end of the string.  String handling functions and output functions like `puts` and `printf` with the `%s` specifier need that 0 terminator in order to process the string correctly.

Strings are stored in arrays of character type, either `char` (for ASCII, UTF-8, or EBCDIC character sets) or `wchar_t` for "wide" strings (character sets that require more than 8 or so bits to encode).  An N-character string requires an array that's *at least* N+1 elements wide to account for the 0 terminator.

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array of character type, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call

```
gets( a[i] );
```

the expression `a[i]` is converted from type "50-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array (`&a[i][0]`)<sup>1</sup>.  `gets` will read characters from standard input and store them to the array starting at that address.  Note that `gets` is no longer part of the standard C library - it was removed in the 2011 version of the standard because it is unsafe.  C does not require any sort of bounds checking on array accesses - if you type in more characters than the target buffer is sized to hold (in this case, 50), those extra characters will be written to memory immediately following the last element of the array, which can cause all sorts of mayhem.  Buffer overflows are a popular malware exploit. You should replace the `gets` call with

```
fgets( a[i], 50, stdin );
```

which will read up to 49 characters into `a[i]` from standard input.  Note that any excess characters are left in the input stream.

Also, the behavior of `fflush` is not defined for input streams<sup>2</sup> - there's no good, safe, *portable* way to clear excess input except to read it using `getchar` or `fgetc`.

---

1. This is why you got the error message you did when you changed `a` from `char [50][50]` to `char [50]` - in that case, `a[i]` has type `char`, not `char *`, and the value of `a[i]` is not an *address*.

   Microsoft's Visual Studio C compiler is a notable exception - it will clear excess input from the input stream.  However, that's specific to MSVC, and not portable across different compilers.  The operation is also a little nonsensical with respect to "flush" semantics.

Answer (score 2):

`char a[50][50]` declares `a` to be an array of 50 arrays of 50 `char`.

Then `a[0]` is an array of 50 `char`, and so is `a[1]`,`a[2]`. `a[3]`, and so on up to `a[49]`. There are 50 separate arrays, and each of them has 50 `char`.

Since `a[0]` is an array of 50 `char`, `a[0][0]` is a `char`. In general, `a[i][j]` is character `j` of array `i`.

`gets(a[i])` says to read characters from input and put them into `a[i]`. For this to work, `a[i]` must be an array of `char`—`gets` reads multiple characters and puts them in the array. If `a[i]` were a single character, `gets` could not work.

Although `gets(a[i])` says to put characters into `a[i]`, it works by passing an address instead of passing the array. When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or the address operator `&`, C automatically converts it to a pointer to its first element. Since `a[i]` is an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element (a pointer to `a[i][0]`). `gets` receives this pointer and uses it to fill in characters that it reads from the standard input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in C this signifies an array of length 0 to 50 of that contains the character value of 50 in each cell of the array

Answer (score -2):

That program seems to store `n` names in the array `a`. It first asks for the number of names, and then the names. The method `char *gets(char *str)` stores each different line in an entry of `a`.

`n` has 2 dimensions. The first refers to the number of names, and the second is for the length of each name. Something like `n[number_of_names][lenght_of_name]`

However, it will probably crash if the user provides an n > 50, or if a name contains more than 50 chars.

Also, `gets()` is dangerous. See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

**EDIT:** Changing `a` to one dimensions makes the program try to store a whole line inside a char, hence the error